# Tomcat Manager Deploying WAR file located on server

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I have a linux server installed CentOS and **Tomcat6**. And i am trying to deploy my jsf application and i created a war file of my project. I am using Tomcat Manager using **Deploy directory or WAR file located on server** with parameters given below [image]

My **war** file is located in wepapps directory as suggested. Than i am giving the **Context Path** to my app name like **/myapp** and giving the **WAR or Directory URL** the url of my application which is like **/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/myapp.war** and last i am leaving empty the value of **XML Configuration**. And when i press the Deploy button Message says **Failed to deploy application at context path /myapp**

Since this is the first experience for me to deploy an app located on server im not sure if i am doing right. I've searched lots of documents already but still cant find a usefull explanation to start my application.
I am realy stucked with this and need your help?

Here is my catalina log file

> 

```
 Sep 5, 2013 1:38:37 p.m. org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
    SEVERE: Begin event threw error
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.ManagedBean
       at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:145)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
       at gnu.xml.stream.SAXParser.parse(libgcj.so.10)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1556)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.modules.MbeansDescriptorsDigesterSource.execute(MbeansDescriptorsDigesterSource.java:238)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.modules.MbeansDescriptorsDigesterSource.loadDescriptors(MbeansDescriptorsDigesterSource.java:216)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.load(Registry.java:689)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.loadDescriptors(Registry.java:800)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.loadDescriptors(Registry.java:780)
       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createRegistry(MBeanUtils.java:1066)
       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.<clinit>(MBeanUtils.java:95)
       at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.<clinit>(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:68)
       at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:145)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
       at gnu.xml.stream.SAXParser.parse(libgcj.so.10)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.10)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
       Sep 5, 2013 1:47:15 p.m. org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.ManagedBean
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:145)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
   at gnu.xml.stream.SAXParser.parse(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1556)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.modules.MbeansDescriptorsDigesterSource.execute(MbeansDescriptorsDigesterSource.java:238)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.modules.MbeansDescriptorsDigesterSource.loadDescriptors(MbeansDescriptorsDigesterSource.java:216)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.load(Registry.java:689)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.loadDescriptors(Registry.java:800)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.loadDescriptors(Registry.java:780)
   at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createRegistry(MBeanUtils.java:1066)
   at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.<clinit>(MBeanUtils.java:95)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.<clinit>(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:68)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:145)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
   at gnu.xml.stream.SAXParser.parse(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.10)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.management.modelmbean.ModelMBeanNotificationBroadcaster not found in org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader{urls=[file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/catalina-tribes.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/tomcat-util.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/tomcat-jdbc.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/tomcat-api.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/ecj-4.2.2.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/catalina-ha.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/catalina-ant.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/jsp-api.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/jasper.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/catalina.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/annotations-api.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/el-api.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/jasper-el.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib/servlet-api.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/bootstrap.jar,file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-juli.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   ...25 more
```

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Applications (.war archives) in `<tomcat>/webapps` are auto-deployed by default (copying `myapp.war` into that directory should be enough). Check `<tomcat>/logs/catalina.out` for any further clues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check the catalina.out file and will inform you if i find a solution..

Comment: I've checked catalina.out file as you suggested but there're tons of errors in it. I made an edit on my post and add log file. I will be appreciated if you figure out the problem.

Comment: It seems that `tomcat-coyote.jar` isn't in your CLASSPATH. How exactly do you start the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem at last. The reason for error is simple actually. We configured our project and created war file using tomcat7. So when we try to deploy and run at server which has previous version of tomcat (tomcat6) it doesnt work. So we installed tomcat7 to that server and it works now. And probably its because tomcat6 doesnt support servlet3 and some of jsf feauters. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have shorted Out that problem Just

```
Step 1:-
Install JDK 1.7.0

step 2:-
Just include Jre Directory when you are Making TOMCAT Server 7. just goto Installed Jre and Just select ADD in option in that and GOTO the Location of your JRE and add that Folder that.

Step3:-
after adding that finish server installation and run your server.
```

that way that will be working.